# How to track changes to the account team in real time?

Tags: apex, trigger, standard-objects

**Question**

Is there anyway to track changes to the account team, i.e. insertions, deletions, updates, in real-time?

**Background**

We're switching away from selling based on an account owner model to a team-based model and want to be able to track who and what changes are being made to the account team.  The only option seems to be a scheduled process that reviews recently modified account team members.  However, we're hoping to have this be a real time tracking system.  I've reviewed all the documentation and it seems like I'm SOL.  Does the community have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So triggers are not possible on Account Teams (Spring'13 enabled this for Opportunity Teams I believe)

Couple of options :

A custom object to model Account Team Members, which lets you have triggers.

Replace Account Team Related List with a custom VF section, which controls all user interaction and can therefore fire off an update to the Account to maybe trigger an outbound message, or make a ws-callout itself. This is assuming all Account Team interactions are via the UI rather than via the API.

The Streaming API (not sure about specifics, but wonder if this is an option)

Comment: +1 for Streaming API. This would be The Right Way, but it suffers `INVALID_FIELD, 'AccountTeamMember' is not supported` exception upon insertion of the PushTopic.

Comment: Could Streaming API be plugged in to track changes of `AccountShare` or `UserRecordAccess`? Bit more work to filter by correct sharing reasons... Pity the team changes don't trigger Chatter updates, that'd be another way to hook up.

Comment: As always, great suggestions.  Seems like the visualforce page account team related list strikes the best balance of retaining the features of the native account team, while still being able to track history (as long as we can keep admins from adding it back to the page layout)